# How to prevent response ambiguity in Dialogflow CX with conflicting information from different files containing the same content?

Tags: database, webhooks, dialogflow-cx, google-generativeai

1. When using **Dialog flow CX** to create an HRMS chatbot, and with the datastore prepared by uploading files to a cloud storage bucket, can data be dynamically updated, or is deleting and reuploading the sole method? If dynamic data editing is possible, what is the process to accomplish it?
2. In the event of conflicting answers between two files, how is the determination made regarding which answer to display, and what approach is used to resolve this conflict?
3. I attempted to modify the entire file post-editing, but found it inefficient. I seek a method to change or edit data without deletion.
4. In the event of conflicting answers between two files, how is the determination made regarding which answer to display, and what approach is used to resolve this conflict?